# how can I use a variable value to define a new variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, url, constants, var

I have a list

```
const StudentCode = {
  Jack: 32658495,
  Rose: 35621548,
  Lita: 63259547,
  Seth: 27956431,
  Cathy: 75821456,
};
```

how can I use these peoples numbers if their names matches another variable result?

We have

```
var name = *selected server-side student names*
```

and by these * signs I mean it's a great list that *name* gives up but it only gives up one name out of that list at the time we call it.

If one of these students is selected by *name variable*, how can I use the number defined in front of that name in const StudentCode to generate a url?

Suppose you get Rose! Then the number for Rose is: 35621548 and the url for example will be https://www.35621548.com. What code can we use to generate this url for example in console?

```
console.log(url)
```

Comment: You seem to have asked this question four times over as many days. Instead of repeating your question, improve your question. Explain why the answer you receive isn't acceptable, or useful, since it's the same answer when the question is answered. And the only answer that seems possible/workable given the information you present.

Comment: Yes I apologise. I will surely remove the meaningless question titles that I asked and I know it. That's a shame.

Comment: Thank you. Though I will advise you to improve the question, and remind you that you were informed of the rules regarding posting duplicate questions in one of your previous questions (asking this same question). Please delete the duplicates as soon as possible.

Comment: Sure. Thanks a million

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```js
if (StudentCode.hasOwnProperty(name){
    const url = `https://www.${StudentCode[name]}.com`
}
```

Comment: *name* cannot be redefined. It is selected by server and gives up one of the names. So at least we will have one *if* clause in your answer.

Comment: Check now it will work

Comment: const StudentCode = {
  Jack: 32658495,
  Rose: 35621548,
  Lita: 63259547,
  Seth: 27956431,
  Cathy: 75821456,
};
var name = "Jack"

if (StudentCode.hasOwnProperty[name])
{
var www = "https://www.studentname.com/code="
var number = ${StudentCode[name]}
    const url = www+number
}
  console.log(url);

Comment: What's wrong? It keeps sending errors about url const!

Comment: @mohsen haqiqat you have defined the url inside the if block and trying to access it outside. Also, you are using `StudentCode.hasOwnProperty[name]` instead of `StudentCode.hasOwnProperty(name)`

Comment: Also, `var number = ${StudentCode[name]}` should be `var number = \`${StudentCode[name]}\``

Comment: I think I need to send a video and speak up my problem! I really don't know how to ask it. Is there a way to send a video?

Answer (score 0):

This function will return you the url on the basis of the student name that is passed in this function.

```
function returnURL(studentName){
    const StudentCode = {
      Jack: 32658495,
      Rose: 35621548,
      Lita: 63259547,
      Seth: 27956431,
      Cathy: 75821456,
    };
    if (!!!StudentCode[studentName]) return "";
    return "https://" + StudentCode[studentName] + ".com";
}

console.log(returnURL("Rose"));
```

Hope, this helps!!

Comment: Whatever that *name* variable states as name is definitely in the above list. So I think we need an if clause at least (if *name* matches one of StudentCode values then the url will be the number in front of him or her+www before and .com after it).

Comment: Can you please check it now??

Comment: So if I replace ("Rose")  in last line with *name* variable. Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
export const studentUrlModule = (function() {
   const studentCode = {
     Jack: 32658495,
     Rose: 35621548,
     Lita: 63259547,
     Seth: 27956431,
     Cathy: 75821456,
   };

   const url = 'https://$code.com'

   const generateUrl = function(code = '') {
     if (!url) {
       throw new Error('Url is not defined')
     } else if (!code) {
       throw new Error('Code is not defined')
     };

     return url.replace('$code', `${code}`);
   }

   function getCode(name = '') {
     const code = studentCode[name];

     if (!code) {
       throw new Error(`There is no code with name(${name}).`);
     }

     return code;
   }

   function getUrl(name = '') {
     if (!name) {
       throw new Error('StudentName is undefined')
     };

     const code = getCode(name);
     const studentUrl = generateUrl(code);

     return studentUrl;
   }

   return {
     generateUrl,
     getCode,
     getUrl,
   };
 }());
```

Maybe it helps. If the code was not founded then it throws an error. Please use try, catch error handlers to handle errors.

-- Update
I updated the code and as you can see it's a module and you need to import it everywhere you like to use this.

if you are not familiar with modules and how to use them inside the browser check documents.

[Mozila documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

[Super Simple Start to ESModules in the Browser](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/super-simple-start-to-es-modules-in-the-browser)

Comment: This code works in testing online but I don't know why isn't it working in my website!

I receive a strange instruction that ask us to use this structure in JavaScript playground!!:
Please use the code below:
```true==function()
{
    //----------define your integers here----------

 
    //----------define your integers here----------
}()```
This looks strange!

Comment: I updated the code and try to use it as a module.

Answer (score 0):

```
const StudentCode = {
    Jack: 32658495,
    Rose: 35621548,
    Lita: 63259547,
    Seth: 27956431,
    Cathy: 75821456,
  };

  let studentName = "Jack"


  const url = `https://${StudentCode[studentName]}.com`

  console.log(url)
```

Comment: Which one can be replaced with *name* variable? "Jack"?